# подключение к SQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь подключится к базе данных sql server по нажатию кнопки (но для начала пытаюсь хотя бы при загрузке страницы).
Установил библиотеки для работы с sql server
`npm install mssql` и `npm install @frangiskos/mssql`

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    "user": document.getElementById('userText'), //default is sa
    "password": document.getElementById('passwordText'),
    "server": document.getElementById('dataSourceText'), // for local machine
    "database": document.getElementById('initialCatalogText'), // name of database
    "options": {
        "encrypt": true
    }
}

sql.connect(config, err => {
    if(err){
        throw err ;
    }
    console.log("Connection Successful !");

    // new sql.Request().query('select 1 as number', (err, result) => {
    //     //handle err
    //     console.dir(result)
    //     // This example uses callbacks strategy for getting results.
    // })

});

sql.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
    console.log("Sql database connection error " ,err);
})
```

```css
@import url("css/normalize.css");

/********Start Первичные настройки сайта********/
*,
*::before,
    /*не изменяет размеры блока*/
*::after{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

/*------------------------------------------
              START indexconnect.html
 -------------------------------------------*/
fieldset.groupbox-border {
    border: 1px groove #ddd ;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em ;
    margin: 1.2em 1.2em 1.2em 1.2em ;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

legend.groupbox-border {
    font-size: 1.2em ;
    font-weight: bold ;
    text-align: left ;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.input-group{
    display: block;
}
.btn-primary{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xl-12">
             <fieldset class="groupbox-border">
                <legend class="groupbox-border">Подключение к БД</legend>

                 <form name="formConnect">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="dataSourceText">Сервер:</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dataSource" id="dataSourceText" required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="initialCatalogText">База данных:</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="initialCatalogText" required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="userText">Пользователь:</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userText" required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="passwordText">Пароль:</label>
                         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordText" required>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="connectBtn" onclick="">Подключиться</button>
                     </div>
                 </form>

             </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->

<!-----------------------------------
    SCRIPTS
--------------------------------------->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Вылетает ошибка `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at scripts.js:36` строка в файле js `const sql = require('mssql');` (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined)

Правильно ли я пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных, в чем ошибка. Есть ли еще какие-то способы подключения.

Comment: А вы этот js скрипт где подключаете? В браузере?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, ну я уже так понял, что так не получиться. Только через API, хотелось передать данные с текстбоксов на странице для подключения к БД по нажатию на кнопку

Comment: Да, напрямую с браузера подключиться к `mssql` нельзя.